# anti-log of spaghetti plot with linear mixed model overlayed in R using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, lme4

I have created a spaghetti plot using `ggplot2` that shows each subject's change in volume over time. Additionally, I have a linear mixed model (random intercept) that shows the effect of known risk factors (eg. age, hypertension, etc.) and the factor of interest: caffeine exposure represented as any vs. none, on volume. All of these factors are treated as fixed effects and the random effect is the patient id. Caffeine is allowed to vary over time (but is not time dependent).

It is known that the volume in these patients changes over time exponentially, so I have modeled the natural log of the volume when creating the linear mixed model. I want to take the estimates from this model and plot them on top of the spaghetti plot, but I want this to be on the original scale (i.e. I want to plot the anti log of the model estimates).

Specifically want to plot two lines. Both lines model the "average individual" in the study (so if the average age is 30, then I multiple the estimate of age by 30) and differ only in the inclusion of caffeine. I have not been able to find a way to do this, but I have been able to plot the spaghetti plot and overlaying regression lines on the log-scale.

Sample code:

```
id <- 1:250
age <- rnorm(250,32.3,5)
race <- rbinom(250,1,0.87)
sex <- rbinom(250,1,0.4)
htn <- rbinom(250,1,0.61)
genetype <- rbinom(250,2,c(0.25,0.22))
caf <- rbinom(250,1,0.79)
vol <- rexp(n = 250, rate = .5)*100
numVisits <- rbinom(250,5,0.25) + 4

baseline <- cbind(id,numVisits,age,race,sex,htn,genetype,caf,vol)

totRace = c();totSex = c();totGene = c();totHtn = c();totCaf = c();
totage = c();totid = c();totVol = c();totvis = c()

for(j in 1:250){
  i = baseline[j,]
  Nid = rep.int(i[1],i[2]); totid = c(totid,Nid)
  Nvis = 1:i[2]; totvis = c(totvis,Nvis)
  Nage = rep.int(i[3],i[2]); totage = c(totage,Nage)
  Nrace = rep.int(i[4],i[2]); totRace = c(totRace, Nrace)
  Nsex = rep.int(i[5],i[2]); totSex = c(totSex,Nsex)
  Ngene = rep.int(i[7],i[2]); totGene = c(totGene,Ngene)
  Nhtn = rep.int(i[6],i[2]); totHtn = c(totHtn,Nhtn)
  Ncaf = rep.int(i[8],i[2]); totCaf = c(totCaf,Ncaf)
  Nvol = sort(c(i[[9]],sample(i[9]:4000, size = i[2] - 1, replace = FALSE)),decreasing = FALSE)
  totVol = c(totVol,Nvol)
}

sampleData <- cbind(totid,as.factor(totvis),totage,as.factor(totRace),as.factor(totSex),as.factor(totHtn),as.factor(totGene),as.factor(totCaf),totVol)
colnames(sampleData) <- c("id","vis","age","race","sex","htn","genetype","caf","vol")
sampleData <- data.frame(sampleData)

### linear mixed model ###
mod1 = lmer(log(vol) ~ age + as.factor(sex) + as.factor(race) + as.factor(htn) + as.factor(genetype) + vis*as.factor(caf) + (1|id), data = sampleData)
summary(mod1)
# this code was edited to make some of the variables categorical #

### spaghetti plot ###
p <- ggplot(data = sampleData, aes(x = vis, y = log(vol), group = id, color = as.factor(caf))) + geom_line()
### spaghetti plot with the regression line ###
fixCoef <- fixef(mod1) # get the coefficients from the linear mixed model
print(fixCoef)
b_No <- fixCoef[1] + fixCoef[2]*32.3 + fixCoef[3]*0.6 + fixCoef[4]*0.87 + fixCoef[5]*0.61 + fixCoef[6]*0.25 + fixCoef[7]*0.22 # intercept for regression line for average person in the study; no caffeine ingestion
b_Yes <- b_No + fixCoef[9] # intercept for regression line for avg person in study; yes caffeine consumption
m_No <- fixCoef[8] # slope for no caffine ingestion
m_Yes <- fixCoef[8] + fixCoef[10] # slope for yes caffeine consumption
q <- p + scale_colour_manual(labels = c("Caffeine Free","Consume Caffeine"), values = c("deepskyblue1", "indianred1")) + geom_abline(intercept = b_No, slope = m_No, colour = "deepskyblue4",size = 1.4) + geom_abline(intercept = b_Yes, slope = m_Yes, colour = "indianred4", size = 1.4) + labs(x = "Years since Baseline", y = "ln(vol), ln(mL/m)", colour = "", title = "Spaghetti Plot of ln(vol) Over Time by Caffeine Intake")
```

I am not sure how to show the output online, but if you run this in R it should work.

#### Minimal Example

```
## make the linear mixed model with only age as the fixed effect and subject as
## the random effect ###
mod2 <- lmer(log(vol) ~ age + vis + (1 | id), data = sampleData)

## the spaghetti plot:
p <- ggplot(data = sampleData, aes(x = vis, y = log(vol), group = id)) + geom_line()
## the new regression lines will be:
### spaghetti plot with the regression line ###
fixCoef <- fixef(mod2) # get the coefficients from the linear mixed model
print(fixCoef)
b <- fixCoef[1] + fixCoef[2] * 32.3  # intercept
m <- fixCoef[2] # slope
q <-
    p + geom_abline(intercept = b, slope = m) + labs(
        x = "Years since Baseline",
        y = "ln(vol), ln(mL/m)",
        colour = "",
        title = "Spaghetti Plot of ln(vol) Over Time by Caffeine Intake"
    )
```

Right now, I can only figure out how to graph q on the ln scale, but I want it to be on the regular scale. So my main question is how to take the anti-log of the mixed model and plot it on the spaghetti plot

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that desired output. You have things like race in the model which appears to be categorical. How do you average over race to get one line? Same for sex. And do you really mean you want to add two more line to the plot? Are you just not able to extract predictions from the model at all? Where exactly are you getting stuck?

Comment: For the categorical risk factors, I am using the proportion of the sample that are 1. So for race, I would multiply the estimate from the mixed model by 0.87 when computing the line for the "average" person in the sample. I want to add 2 more lines to the spaghetti plot - these lines are derived from the mixed model (in the code from my original post) and differ in the inclusion of caffeine. I am getting stuck at taking the anti-log of the two lines I want to add.

Comment: So did you mean to fit those are numeric or categorical. you used `as.factor()` but then put that in `cbind()` which convereted them to numeric. For proper categorical variables, there is a reference category and each non-reference value get's it's own parameter. There is not just one coefficient for those covariates. I can't tell if what you did was a mistake or intentional.

Comment: That was a mistake. All variables are supposed to be categorical except for age, vis and vol (volume).

Comment: Can you make a **minimal** example? Would your code work with just age and race? Seems like starting simple and generalizing from there would be a good approach.

Comment: @Gregor The code will work with just age and race. I will add in an example, up to the point where I get stuck, which is taking the anti-log of the regression line and plotting this on top of the spaghetti plot.

Comment: Do you really want number of visits to be a `factor`? It seems like you are expecting a smooth exponential curve to connect the different `vis` values, but with `vis` as a categorical variable this will not be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, first in an effort to make caffeine have an effect on the response in your sample data, I made changed the `vol` line to this:

```
vol <- rexp(n = n, rate = .5) * 100 * exp(caf * rnorm(n, 0, 3))
```

I also assumed you meant `vis` to be continuous, not a factor. For creating `sampleData`, I used one `data.frame` call instead of `cbind`, `colNames<-`, `data.frame`:

```
sampleData <- data.frame(
        id = totid,
        vis = totvis,
        age = totage,
        race = factor(totRace),
        sex = factor(totSex),
        htn = factor(totHtn),
        genetype = factor(totGene),
        caf = factor(totCaf),
        vol = totVol
)
```

Then, let's fit a simple model with age, race, and caffeine:

```
mod2 <- lmer(log(vol) ~ age + vis + caf + (1 | id), data = sampleData)
fixCoef <- fixef(mod2)
```

Rather than hand-type out vector multiplication, we will set up a dummy data frame of data to predict on and use `%*%` to do the predictions:

```
## dummy data. expand.grid gives all combinations of its arguments
## I chose 50 values of vis to generate a nice smooth curve
## better to calculate means on the fly than hard-code them
##    to avoid bugs
pred_dat = expand.grid(
    age = mean(sampleData$age),
    vis = seq(from = min(sampleData$vis), to = max(sampleData$vis), length.out = 50),
    caf = factor(0:1)
)

## create a model matrix and multiply by the fixed coefs to generate predictions
pred_dat$pred = as.vector(model.matrix(~ age + vis + caf, data = pred_dat) %*% fixCoef)
```

Now we can get to the plotting. I tweaked some of these settings

```
## spaghetti plot
p <- ggplot(data = sampleData, aes(x = vis, y = vol, group = id)) + 
    geom_line(alpha = 0.2) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:8)
p

## add model prediction
q <- p +
    geom_line(data = pred_dat,
              aes(x = vis, y = exp(pred), color = factor(caf)),
              inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    labs(
        x = "Years since Baseline",
        y = "ln(vol), ln(mL/m)",
        colour = "Caffeine",
        title = "Spaghetti Plot of vol Over Time by Caffeine Intake"
    )
q
```

[image]

Obviously the model doesn't fit the fake data very well, hopefully your real data is a better match :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, @Gregor !  I am running into a few problems when applying your programming style to the larger model. When I am making the pred_dat variable, I am having problems adding in the genetype variable because it has 3 different levels instead of 2, so in the model output I have two different estimates for the levels (one is baseline). Additionally, I have time (vis) and caffeine as an interaction term. How can I adjust your code to fit these additional estimates? I tried to read about the functions expand.grid and model.matrix but I am not familiar with them.

Comment: Generally if you use the same formula in `model.matrix` as you use in your model, without the random effects, things should work. Your data in `pred_dat` needs to have the same columns and classes as the data you trained your model on.

Comment: For categorical variables with 2 levels, there's no difference between a `factor` and a `numeric` with values 1 and 0. Using the mean to represent an "average individual" somewhere between the two levels is a little strange, but at least the matrix multiplication works out.

Comment: For a factor with 3 or more levels there is not a clear way to define an "average" individual: you have coefficient estimates for each non-reference level. Instead, I would recommend generating predictions with each of the factor levels and plotting them separately (maybe more lines on the plot, maybe use facets?). I suppose you could do a weighted average of the predictions, but at that point you're straying well outside normal statistical practice. Might as well just omit genetype from the model rather than model it and then average it out.